# mu4e error : Database empty; try indexing some messages

Tags: mu4e

I recently setup mu4e. My Setup :
emacs25, mu 0.9.18, macOS Sierra

I used `mbsync` to download my emails.

When I do `M-x mu4e`, I get error `error in process sentinel: Database empty; try indexing some messages`

But I have :)

I checked `mu4e-maildir`. It is correct (which is where `mbsync` has downloaded the messages.)

`mu index` (as well as `mu index --maildir=~/Maildir` just in case) also worked well.

I can use `mu find <pattern>` successfully.

But `mu4e` can't seem to find the DB

I think this is some configuration mismatch.

**How do I troubleshoot this ?**

---

References :

- About 4 year old issue, without conclusive solution with exact same error : https://github.com/djcb/mu/issues/198 (Edit: I read http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.mail.mu.general/938 thread. I mentioned above, I am **not** using `procmail`. Using `mbsync` as mentioned above)
- I have asked this question first on reddit (Albeit it started in slightly different context where I couldn't even get `mu4e` to work. But now I'm past that. https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/5srva7/mu4e_0918_emailing_with_emacs_now_even_better/deyf717/

Comment: What's the value of these variables `mu4e-maildir`, `mu4e-trash-folder`,  `mu4e-refile-folder`, `mu4e-sent-folder`, `mu4e-drafts-folder`?

Comment: @nasseralshammari See my answer. The problem above was (possibly) caused due to my non-standard setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came back to the setup after almost 3 months.
I enabled mu4e in my `.spacemacs` and uncommented all the other settings related to `mu4e`, and what do you know? It works !!

Off course, I'm not saying this is magic.

But I have a hypothesis.

Some time ago, I had moved all the spacemacs setup into `~/spacemacs` and I used to start the emacs as `HOME=~/spacemacs emac &`

I think this used to throw off a lot of software. I used to ran into "unexplained" behavior, where "normal" troubleshooting doesn't help.

So last week, I moved off that setup, and now my `.spacemacs` and `.emacs.d` etc all are in my actual HOME (i.e. `~`) like everyone else.

I think this alone has solved several problems.

`mu4e` may be one of those.

---

I now start emacs from the dashboard using the icon (macOS) - which earlier I couldn't do, since I didn't know how to set different HOME when launching from the dashboard. So I was forced to always use the term (I'm not complaining. Just sayin)